# How do you write that a unique element exists in a collection?

Tags: notation, quantifiers

I'm a bit rusty on my math notations and I'd like to write that:

> It exists a unique element $z$ such that $z$ belongs to the collection of values returned by $f(x,y)$

Honestly I'm not just rusty I'm also mostly ignorant of math except from basic functions and basic matrix operations.

I'm in the context of computer programming and I want to write down a specification, and for my own curiosity (and fun) I was wondering how this would be written in a more scientific way.

I'd go with something like:

> $\exists z\in S$ such that...

And then I'm lost with how to specify that $S$ is the result of $f(x,y)$.

Some usage of $P(z)$ maybe ?

Also $S$ means "set" right? So it doesn't work because $z$ may be present multiple times, but IDK if there's a symbol for such "collection".

I've googled around but it's a bit hard to find the right keywords for searching something like this.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

I knew I'd make a mistake while posting this... I've mistakenly named $x$, $x$, leading to the confusion that it is the same $x$ that is in $f(x,y)$, while actually it is not.

So I have renamed it $z$, sorry about that.

**EDIT 2**:

There are multiples solutions that have been provided in the answers and for this I'm thankful, but I can't identify if one matches what I want.

And there are also a lot of questions which I believe are due to me not giving enough details or not expressing myself correctly, and I realize now that I have made a mistake on the way so I will try to add more details and maybe it will help to make the answers converge.

I have a function, say $f$, that given two arguments, say $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, will return a collection of values, say $S$ whose values are taken from $Z$.

And I want $S$ to contain only $z$ (possibly multiple times).

Given $S1$ and $S2$ the respective results of $f(x1,y1)$ and $f(x2,y2)$, there can not be a given $z$ that would be present in both $S1$ and $S2$.

For the record, $y1$ may be equal to $y2$.

Also $y$ depends on $x$ so I guess we start with the second part of what @celtschk said in his comment and simplify:

> $$S = \bigg\{f(x, g(x)) : x ∈ X \bigg\} ⊂ Z$$

But the first part should be:

> "$z$ exists at least once and is unique in $S$"

and I don't know how to write that :)

Comment: Since you're not quantifying over $y$, I'm just guessing here: one possible way, using standard notation, is $\exists !x\exists y((x,y)\in \text{dom}(f)\land x=f(x,y))$.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that x (now z) is not the same as the x used in f(x,y). Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you mean the function returns a set for each $x$ and $y$, or do you mean the set of values $f$ may return when applied to arbitrary $x$ and $y$? Or in formal terms, if your function is $f:X\times Y\to Z$, is $S\in Z$, or is $S=\{f(x,y): x\in X\land y\in Y\}\subset Z$?

Comment: What is $P(z)$?

Comment: @celtschk I've edited the question to add details, and I think the answer to your comment is the second option.

Comment: +1 for your curiousity - but in your spec I'd stick with the perfectly good English statement.It's just as scientific as the formal version, which any reader would have to translate back into English to understand.

Comment: @Masacroso I've stumble upon this notation on wikipedia while searching and I thought it would express some kind of predicate and might be usable.

Comment: @EthanBolker oh yes, sure I agree, it's more for curiosity than anything else :-)

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you want. If $S$ contains only $z$ and $S$ is the image of the function $f$ then we can write $f(X,Y)=S=\{z\}$, and $f(x,y)=z$ for all $(x,y\in X\times Y$. But if $y$ depends on $x$ then the function doesnt have two variables, just one, so the expression $f(x,y)$ is wrong. Please write the complete function $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to say

$$\exists! (x, y) ~:~ f(x, y) = z$$

or less abbreviated:

$$\exists x~\exists y~ \bigg(f(x, y) = z \land \bigg(\forall x_2 ~ \forall y_2~ ~:~ f(x_2, y_2) = z \implies (x_2 = x \land y_2 = y)\bigg)\bigg)$$

If I interpret your question correctly, you are trying to say that $z$ exists exactly once in the image of $f$.

If you are comfortable with set comprehension, then you could also write:

$$\left|\bigg\{ x, y ~:~ f(x,y) = z \bigg\}\right| = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$\exists !\ x\in S \text { s.t. } \exists\ y \text { s.t. }(x,y)\in Dom(f) \land f(x,y)=x.$$

There exists a unique $x\in S$ such that there exists an $y$, such that the tuple $(x,y)$ is in the domain of $f$ and for which $f(x,y)=x$.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that x (now z) is not the same as the x used in f(x,y). Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully understand, what sets is your function mapping from and to.

Judging by your first post, I'd say that $S$ is probably a multiset. (That is a set together with multiplicities for each element.)

So, you function definition would look like:

$f: X\times Y \to (S, m)$, where $m: S \to N$

Then the constraint on $z$ would look like:

$\exists! z:  f(x,y) = (S, m) \land m(z)=1 $

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that x (now z) is not the same as the x used in f(x,y). Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Adjusted the notation :-).

Answer (score 0):

First we define the function $f$ properly, i.e. we define it domain and codomain:

$$f:X\times Y\to D$$

Then we just write

$$\exists !z\in f(X,Y)\text{ such that...(whatever)}$$

where $f(X,Y)$ is the image of the function. For any function the image is a subset of the codomain, i.e.

$$f(X,Y)\subseteq D$$

You need to complete the reason why you are defining this unique $z$ if not the statement is confuse.